# White circle problem appearing on mobile device

Tags: html, css

I have a picture and when you click on the picture, the bootstrap model opens. (Lightbox)

So far there is no problem. But in the mobile version, there is a problem around the picture.

The problem stems from the width and height. Automatically adjusts the height and width, but does not click on the picture.

```
.testing {
  width:150px;height:150px;position:fixed;z-index:123123;right:3px;bottom:0;}
```

The problem is solved this way, but it doesn't click.

```
.testing {
width:auto;height:auto;position:fixed;z-index:123123;right:3px;bottom:0;}
```

The problem white circle appearing on the mobile is in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jTov.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

If it's the size adjustment that's causing the problem, you might want to change your `width` to `min-width` and `height` to `min-height`(e.g. `min-width: 300px;`) instead. So you can set that it doesn't go below the size where the image function would still work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is the same as auto when you give minimum and maximum values. The white circle is constantly coming.

Comment: Did you put fixed values after you modified it to `min-height` and `min-width` (e.g. `min-height: 300px;`). Using min or max modifier without giving it a fix value would make it useless.

Comment: Yes, I tried in different values. the white circle shows the clickable area, but it should not be there. 

https://i.imgur.com/6eyVXOR.jpg

My domain address is showing in the screenshot.

This problem does not appear responsive on the browser. appears on the phone.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting it then? Ctrl + Shift + C and point to highlight that element, click on it. It will display the name of the container of that white circle. as well as the stylings used to display it.

Comment: This problem only appears on mobile devices so I cannot view the source code. It does not appear when I do Ctrl + Shift + C, but it does appear when logging into the website with the phone.

I think the problem is the height and width because when you auto make these values, the problem disappears.

But the modal is not clicked on.